# How to add a new column called status as string to an existent table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the table called Article and I would like add the status column to the Article table.

Comment: Have you actually attemped any research into solving the problem like [for example reading the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-tables)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

and migrate it:

```
rails db:migrate
```